# Punctuation, and whether one's needed in the given sentence

Tags: punctuation

I need someone in my life I can talk about science and certain periods of history to.

Is it okay to construct sentences the way the sentence above has been constructed?
Should there be any kind of punctuation between **history** and **to**?

Comment: ....who i can talk to about .........

Comment: I've downvoted the question only to flag it as one that learners need not read for it would only serve to create in their minds a  needless doubt and give them an example sentence which a native speaker would be very unlikely to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No punctuation between history and to. The sentence is not (I think) actually ungrammatical: A simpler sentence "I need someone to talk about science to" seems correct.

But you may consider rephrasing. The long phrase "about science and certain periods of history" has the effect of leaving the "to" dangling. The word "to" is part of "talk to someone", acting as a preposition.

Try "...talk to about science and..."

Or (quite formally in style) "I need someone in my life to whom I can talk about ..."

Comment: But would you say the sentence I used is grammatically incorrect?